# Canonical way to remove multiple bytes from buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer, node.js-buffer

Say I have a simple Buffer in Node.js like so:

```
const bytes = Buffer.from('abcdefg');
```

this buffer instance has `slice` and `concat` as methods, but I am really not sure how to use these to basically create the functionality of pop/shift/splice of an array.

here are the Buffer docs: https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html

What I am basically looking to do is read/remove the first X number of bytes, like so:

```
function read(x){

// return the first x number of bytes from buffer
// and remove those bytes from the buffer
// side-effects be damned for the moment
}
```

here's what I have but it seems pretty "wrong" to me even though it also seems to work:

```
let items = Buffer.from('abcdefg');

function read(x){
    const b = items.slice(0,x);
    items = items.slice(x,items.length);
    return b;
}

console.log(String(read(4)));
console.log(String(items));
```

Is there a better way to do this?

also, I am not sure if read is the right word, but pop would connote an array...what's the right word to use the describe what this function does?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [Node.js API](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer):

> Instances of the Buffer class are similar to arrays of integers but correspond to fixed-sized, raw memory allocations outside the V8 heap. **The size of the Buffer is established when it is created and cannot be resized.**

Which is why there is no `.pop()` method for `Buffer` because it isn't an operation for something that is fixed-size in nature unlike an array. Same goes for `shift` and `splice`. You can't extend the already allocated `Buffer` but you can create new ones.

Using `.slice()` won't give you a new `Buffer`, instead, returns a subset of the memory occupied by the original `Buffer`. While that approach works, there could be a possibility that some other variable still references the original `Buffer` in which case, modifications made to the subset you got from `.slice()` could carry over to the original `Buffer` as well.

Given the nature of `Buffer` and the kind of operations you seem to want, it's best to first convert `items` into a string. You can then perform all the operations you mentioned by splitting using `.split('')`. Once you're done, you can join the split string and create a new `Buffer` using `Buffer.from(string)` and assign it back to `items`. This way, your code will be much more clear.